# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. (in laravel)

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I am installing a package with this command

> composer require jenssegers/mongodb

And the output is this

```
 Using version ^3.0 for jenssegers/mongodb ./composer.json has been
 created Loading composer repositories with package information
 Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could
 not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

   Problem 1
     - jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.0 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2].
     - jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.1 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2].
     - jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.2 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2].
     - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
     - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
     - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
     - Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.0 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2].

   To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini
 files:
     - /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
     - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini
     - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
     - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini
     - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
     - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini
     - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
     - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
     - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
> 
> Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

My composer.json is this

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    } }
```

I've tried different solutions, also upgraded my php version from 5.5.9 to 5.6.2. What can be the possible solution?

Comment: As the error message says, your system is missing the `ext-mongodb` PHP extension. Have you tried following installation instructions for that package? The first thing it says is "Make sure you have the MongoDB PHP driver installed. You can find installation instructions at http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.php "

Comment: Yes, u were right. I installed the mongodb extension successfully after resolving errors. But the error is still same.